# What is plugin bag?

Tags: 8

I fail to see the difference between plugin bag and plugin manager. As I look at it both just instantiate plugins with optional configuration.

Comment: Some background if it helps: 
https://drupal.org/node/1869566
https://drupal.org/node/1878416

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the plugin bag is a [container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container%5f%28abstract%5fdata%5ftype%29) for plugins that are lazily instantiated when needed. In short, you create a plugin bag instance passing the settings to the constructor, where the settings array is used to get the plugin IDs; each time a plugin is requested through [PluginBag::get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Plugin!PluginBag.php/function/PluginBag%3a%3aget/8), it will be created with [PluginBag:initializePlugin()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Plugin!PluginBag.php/function/PluginBag%3a%3ainitializePlugin/8) only when necessary.

A plugin manager is used to discover and instantiate single plugins; it is up to your code not creating a plugin that was already created.

The [default plugin bag implementation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Plugin!DefaultPluginBag.php/class/DefaultPluginBag/8) is described as follows:

> A plugin bag is used to contain plugins that will be lazily instantiated. The configurations of each potential plugin are passed in, and the configuration key containing the plugin ID is specified by `self::$pluginKey`.

Answer (score 1):

`PluginBag` has [now been renamed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2352673) to `LazyPluginCollection` to "more accurately convey its purpose". That change along with the background given in the change record and kiamlaluno's existing answer should clear it up:

> The concept of PluginBags was introduced by views and then expanded to a half dozen other entity types. PluginBags provide a way to lazily instantiate a set of plugin instances. The suffix "Bag" was chosen due to its assumed similarity to Symfony objects like ParameterBag, FlashBag, etc. However, "Bag" is supposed to mean that the object contains a set of variables or parameters (values), but that's not what PluginBag actually does.
>
> PluginBag is in fact an ordered map of values or other objects. The right name for that is a Collection. Additionally, PluginBag (or PluginCollection) doesn't explain its true feature, the laziness. Therefore, LazyPluginCollection makes the most sense.